# Compare two dictionaries and check if some values do not exist

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got two lists of dictionaries as below:

```
string1 =[
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7},
  {"name": "Weranika", "age": 18}
]
string2 =[  {"name": "Tom", "age": 8},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]
```

And I want to print key/value for item which doesn't exists in the second list of dictionary.

In my case output should return:

```
{"name": "Weranika", "age": 18}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us.

Comment: You can just loop through the dictionary and see if they match

Comment: What do you want to do about `Tom`, which has a different age in each list?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify, that I need to take into account such results where only the value for key = "name" does not exists in the second list of dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the dictionaries in `string1` and check if a name in it exists in the set of names in `string2`:

```
names = set(d['name'] for d in string2)
not_in_string2 = [dct for dct in string1 if dct['name'] not in names]
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Weranika', 'age': 18}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def compare(list_dict_1, list_dict_2):
    return [item for item in list_dict_1 if item not in list_dict_2]
```

Comment: Should be `...if item not in...`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify, that I need to take into account such results where only  the value for key = "name" does not exists in the second list of dict.

Answer (score 1):

```
str1  = [i["name"] for i in string1]
```

get name in the string

```
str2  = [i["name"] for i in string2]
```

name not in string2 but in 1

```
not_in_string_2 = list(set(str1) ^ set(str2))
```

index of the value not in sring2

```
index = []
for x,i in enumerate(string1):
    if i["name"] in not_in_string_2:
        index.append(x)
for i in index:
   print(string1[i])
```

print the result

Answer (score 0):

This method will work even if the lists are in a different order:

First of all, we need to do some processing to turn each dictionary into an *immutable* object.  This is so we can add them to a `set`, which is an unsorted container that allows fast membership checking, along with other features.

```
processed_string1 = set((d["name"], d["age"]) for d in string1)
processed_string2 = set((d["name"], d["age"]) for d in string2)
```

Then we can use the `set`'s `difference` method do get the items that are in the first set, but not the second:

```
result_set = processed_string1.difference(processed_string2)
```

Then we just have to convert back to a dictionary:

```
result_list = [{"name": t[0], "age": t[1]} for t in result_set]
```